# What is gap milliseconds in naver-pinpoint

Tags: performance, api, apm

We use pinpoint in firm for monitoring our Application's performance. While analyzing an API, I saw a field named GAP(ms). Please help me understand what does it mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the field info if you click '?' button in the upper-right corner of each graph.

Comment: Gap refers to [Elapsed time between the start of the previous method and the entry of this method](https://github.com/naver/pinpoint/blob/f7b9f41b43b85a91298c0757891cf940f867ba3f/web/src/main/webapp/v2/src/assets/i18n/en.json#L300) Check this [sample image](https://ibin.co/4hAGuWPNH6VM.png) displaying the tooltip